# How to generate a script with salt-stack with newlines

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to build a script using salt-stack and jinja. It is a result which I want to get:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 1 &&
echo 2 &&
echo 3 &&
echo 4
```

I have script:

**init.sls**

```
{% set cmds = [] %}
{% for id in [1, 2, 3, 4] %}
{% do cmds.append("echo " ~ id) %}
{% endfor %}

/tmp/test.sh:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://test.sh.jinja
    - template: jinja
    - mode: 0775
    - require:
      - file:     /tmp
    - context:
      cmds : '{{ cmds | join(" &&\n") }}'
```

**test.sh.jinja**

```
#!/bin/bash

{{ cmds  }}
```

**RESULT**

> cat /tmp/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 1 && echo 2 && echo 3 && echo 4
```

So newlines were removed. How to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick look at: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#list-files
Reveals:

```
    - context:
      cmds : {{ cmds | join(' && \n') }}
```

Comment: Yes, it helps inside of template. But it crashes in "- context" as variable. So the correct way is to use it in template `test.sh.jinja`.